# Add styling rules in pandoc tables for odt/docx output (table borders)

Tags: docx, pandoc, odt

I'm generating some odt/docx reports via markdown using knitr and pandoc and am now wondering how you'd go about formating tables. Primarily I'm interested in adding rules (at least top, bottom and one below the header, but being able to add arbitrary ones inside the table would be nice too).

Running the following example from the pandoc documentation through pandoc (without any special parameters) just yields a "plain" table without any kind of rules/colours/guides (in either `-t odt` or `-t docx`).

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Fruit         | Price         | Advantages         |
+===============+===============+====================+
| Bananas       | $1.34         | - built-in wrapper |
|               |               | - bright color     |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Oranges       | $2.10         | - cures scurvy     |
|               |               | - tasty            |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

I've looked through the "styles" for the possibility of specifying table formating in a reference .docx/.odt but found nothing obvious beyond "table header" and "table contents" styles, both of which seem to concern only the formatting of text within the table.

Being rather unfamiliar with WYSIWYG-style document processors I'm lost as to how to continue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's how I searched how to do this:

The way to add a table in Docx is to use the `<w:tbl>` tag. So I searched for this in the github repository, and found it [in this file](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/7c980f39bf1cff941d3e78056fd69e0b371833e3/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Docx.hs) (called Writers/Docx.hs, so it's not a big surprise)

```
blockToOpenXML opts (Table caption aligns widths headers rows) = do
  let captionStr = stringify caption
  caption' <- if null caption
                 then return []
                 else withParaProp (pStyle "TableCaption")
                      $ blockToOpenXML opts (Para caption)
  let alignmentFor al = mknode "w:jc" [("w:val",alignmentToString al)] ()
  let cellToOpenXML (al, cell) = withParaProp (alignmentFor al)
                                    $ blocksToOpenXML opts cell
  headers' <- mapM cellToOpenXML $ zip aligns headers
  rows' <- mapM (\cells -> mapM cellToOpenXML $ zip aligns cells)
           $ rows
  let borderProps = mknode "w:tcPr" []
                    [ mknode "w:tcBorders" []
                      $ mknode "w:bottom" [("w:val","single")] ()
                    , mknode "w:vAlign" [("w:val","bottom")] () ]
  let mkcell border contents = mknode "w:tc" []
                            $ [ borderProps | border ] ++
                            if null contents
                               then [mknode "w:p" [] ()]
                               else contents
  let mkrow border cells = mknode "w:tr" [] $ map (mkcell border) cells
  let textwidth = 7920  -- 5.5 in in twips, 1/20 pt
  let mkgridcol w = mknode "w:gridCol"
                       [("w:w", show $ (floor (textwidth * w) :: Integer))] ()
  return $
    [ mknode "w:tbl" []
      ( mknode "w:tblPr" []
        ( [ mknode "w:tblStyle" [("w:val","TableNormal")] () ] ++
          [ mknode "w:tblCaption" [("w:val", captionStr)] ()
          | not (null caption) ] )
      : mknode "w:tblGrid" []
        (if all (==0) widths
            then []
            else map mkgridcol widths)
      : [ mkrow True headers' | not (all null headers) ] ++
      map (mkrow False) rows'
      )
    ] ++ caption'
```

I'm not familiar at all with Haskell, but I can see that the border-style is hardcoded, since there is no variable in it:

```
let borderProps = mknode "w:tcPr" []
                    [ mknode "w:tcBorders" []
                      $ mknode "w:bottom" [("w:val","single")] ()
                    , mknode "w:vAlign" [("w:val","bottom")] () ]
```

## What does that mean ?

That means that you can't change the style of the docx tables with the current version of PanDoc. Howewer, there's a way to get your own style.

## How to get your own style ?

1. Create a Docx Document with the style you want on your table (by creating that table)
2. Change the extension of that file and unzip it
3. Open `word/document.xml` and search for the `<w:tbl>`
4. Try to find out how your style translates in XML and change the borderProps according to what you see.

Here's a test with a border-style I created:
[image: Custom border style]

And here is the corresponding XML:

```
<w:tblBorders>
  <w:top w:val="dotted" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="C0504D" w:themeColor="accent2"/>
  <w:left w:val="dotted" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="C0504D" w:themeColor="accent2"/>
  <w:bottom w:val="dotted" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="C0504D" w:themeColor="accent2"/>
  <w:right w:val="dotted" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="C0504D" w:themeColor="accent2"/>
  <w:insideH w:val="dotted" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="C0504D" w:themeColor="accent2"/>
  <w:insideV w:val="dotted" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="C0504D" w:themeColor="accent2"/>
</w:tblBorders>
```

## What about odt ?

I didn't have a look at it yet, ask if you don't find by yourself using a similar method.

Hope this helps and don't hesitate to ask something more

Comment: I'll accept this one, since it was the first. I didn't even think of simply checking the code (or perhaps I'm just too lazy and prefer letting other people do it ;))! Thanks!

Comment: It's not always that easy to check the code when your not familiar with what's happening behind, eg how a document is structured, how table is represented in docx. So it's normal.

Comment: Thanks ! Have a look at my opensource project for docx, maybe you need that too: https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater

Answer (score 11):

Same suggestion as edi9999: hack the xml content of converted docx. And the following is my R code for doing that.

The `tblPr` variable contains the definition of style to be added to the tables in docx. You could modify the string to satisfy your own need.

```
require(XML)

docx.file <- "report.docx"
tblPr <- '<w:tblPr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:tblStyle w:val="a8"/><w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/><w:tblBorders><w:top w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/><w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/><w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/><w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/><w:insideH w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/><w:insideV w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/></w:tblBorders><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:tblPr>'

## unzip the docx converted by Pandoc
system(paste("unzip", docx.file, "-d temp_dir"))
document.xml <- "temp_dir/word/document.xml"

doc <- xmlParse(document.xml)
tbl <- getNodeSet(xmlRoot(doc), "//w:tbl")
tblPr.node <- lapply(1:length(tbl), function (i)
                   xmlRoot(xmlParse(tblPr)))
added.Pr <- names(xmlChildren(tblPr.node[[1]]))
for (i in 1:length(tbl)) {
    tbl.node <- tbl[[i]]
    if ('tblPr' %in% names(xmlChildren(tbl.node))) {
        children.Pr <- xmlChildren(xmlChildren(tbl.node)$tblPr)
        for (j in length(added.Pr):1) {
            if (added.Pr[j] %in% names(children.Pr)) {
                replaceNodes(children.Pr[[added.Pr[j]]],
                             xmlChildren(tblPr.node[[i]])[[added.Pr[j]]])
            } else {
                ## first.child <- children.Pr[[1]]
                addSibling(children.Pr[['tblStyle']],
                           xmlChildren(tblPr.node[[i]])[[added.Pr[j]]],
                           after=TRUE)
            }
        }
    } else {
        addSibling(xmlChildren(tbl.node)[[1]], tblPr.node[[i]], after=FALSE)
    }
}

## save hacked xml back to docx
saveXML(doc, document.xml, indent = F)
setwd("temp_dir")
system(paste("zip -r ../", docx.file, " *", sep=""))
setwd("..")
system("rm -fr temp_dir")
```

Comment: In there not a more elegant approach than hacking the *XML*, such as applying the desired table style (from `reference.docx`) via a *Pandoc* [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html)?

Answer (score 7):

edi9999 has the best answer but here's what I do:

When creating the docx, use a reference docx to get styles. That reference will contain a heap of other styles that just aren't used by Pandoc to create, but they are still in there. Typically you'll get the default sets, but you can add a new table style too.

Then, you only need to update the word\document.xml file to reference the new table style, and you can do that programmatically (by unzipping, running sed, and updating the docx archive), eg:

```
7z.exe x mydoc.docx word\document.xml
sed "s/<w:tblStyle w:val=\"TableNormal\"/<w:tblStyle w:val=\"NewTableStyle\"/g" word\document.xml > word\document2.xml
copy word\document2.xml word\document.xml /y
7z.exe u mydoc.docx word\document.xml
```

Comment: This answer combined with the --reference-docx= option is a killer!

Comment: This is great, powershell version of same technique here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72469169/22194

Answer (score 4):

Add a table style named "TableNormal" in `reference.docx`.

Comment: This didn't work for me as Word (2010) complained about that style being reserved.

Comment: Actually when adding a table style named "Table" it worked for me

Comment: Table or TableNormal is built in sytle, just modify it would work.

Comment: Table and TableNormal are built in styles and I cant see a way to edit them, they dont appear in the Table Style Gallery

Answer (score 4):

Using a reference docx file and then python-docx does the job pretty easily :

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/

First convert your document to docx :

**Bash :**

```
pandoc --standalone --data-dir=/path/to/reference/ --output=/tmp/xxx.docx input_file.md
```

> Notes :
>
> - `/path/to/reference/` points to the folder containing `reference.docx`
> - `reference.docx` is a file containing the styles you need for docx elements

Then give the tables of your document the style you want to use :

**Python :**

```
import docx
document = docx.Document('/tmp/xxx.docx')
for table in document.tables:
    table.style = document.styles['custom_style'] # custom_style must exist in your reference.docx file
document.save("target.docx") # thank you Anish
```

Comment: Is that package `pydocx` or `python-docx`? Does it work outside Windows? Where is the documentation for that class `docx.Document`?

Comment: that is `python-docx`. Yes it works outside windows. And there is the `docx.Document` documentation : 
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#document-constructor
It still has some limitations though, but it's the most complete tool I've found to build docx files.

Comment: The python suggestion is wonderful! I only want to add that a `document.save("target.docx")` is required or the changes made to `document` do not seem to persist on disk.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a table style what every you want called "Table" in the reference-doc file。And update pandoc to latest.

Answer (score 2):

I really liked [gbjbaanb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30917615/22194) - here's a powershell version:

Background: Set up a PanDoc `--reference-doc` template as described in the [pandoc documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) for the `--reference-doc` parameter

Open up Word and create a new custom table style in the template doc. In our example that custom table style is called 'MyCustomTable'

Generate your word doc using the `--reference-doc` parameter - the custom table style will be included in the doc, you just have to insert its name in the right place. This bit of powershell will do that for you:

```
$outFile = "C:\Path\To\Your\Doc.docx"
$workFolder = "C:\Some\Temp\Folder\Somewhere\"
# then this replaces table style in $outFile:
$zipFile = $outFile.Replace(".docx",".zip")
Rename-Item $outFile $zipFile 
Expand-Archive $zipFile -DestinationPath $workFolder -Force
$wordXml = Get-Content "${workFolder}Word\Document.xml"
$updatedXml = $wordXml.Replace('<w:tblStyle w:val="Table" />','<w:tblStyle w:val="MyCustomTable" />')
Set-Content -Path "${workFolder}Word\Document.xml" -Value $updatedXml
Compress-Archive -Path "${workFolder}*" -DestinationPath $zipFile -Force
Rename-Item $zipFile $outFile
```

... where $outFile is the docx, and $workFolder is a temp folder somewhere.

In some earlier versions of PanDoc, instead of seaching for `<w:tblStyle w:val="Table" />` you'll need to search for `<w:tblStyle w:val="TableNormal" />`

Answer (score -1):

add filter and custom your own Table style, see lua filter: https://github.com/ZhouJunjun/TyporaLuaFilter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).